# REGEX for Credit Card not working with "or"

Tags: regex

I know that regex for some CC are:

- Visa: `^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})`
- Mastercard: `^5[1-5][0-9]{14}`
- Amex: `^3[47][0-9]{13}`
- Diners Club: `^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}`

If I try them individually they work.
But if I do

```
^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3}) | ^5[1-5][0-9]{14} | ^3[47][0-9]{13} | ^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}
```

I only got `false` as return.  Should be `|` as `OR`?
BTW, need one single regex for all CC.
I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Most likely the spaces are killing it.

Comment: Are you sure you do not need `$` at the end, too? Try `^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11})$`

Comment: You have spaces in your expressions. Does your regexp library not treat the spaces as characters to match? As the previous comment states, you need to put in sync the search mode and use of `^` and `$` (it may match start/end of line or of start/end of a complete text you pass to library's match function according to settings/implementation)

Comment: Visa card numbers can be 13 or 16 digits long.  That's why the last 3 digits are separated into their own group, so they can be made optional: `(?:[0-9]{3})?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionaly to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) answer, for your kind of scenarios a nice way to understand and to improve regexs is by using a tool like debuggex.

So, if I use your expression you can easily see the issues you have. For instance, this is the case for your expression:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

As you can see, there some spaces (shown with `_`). There are clearly some typos.

So, you can improve and fix your regex by using:

```
^(?:4[0-9]{15}|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])‌​[0-9]{11})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: After reading the first part of your answer, I got an impression that `_` denotes a user error at debuggex :) while the spaces are shown that way on the diagram.

Comment: Did not know this tool. It indeed helps to visualize if something is wrong. The spaces never occours me. Thank you for the explanation and help!

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that a caret is a beginning of a string and a pipe is an alternation operator. However, spaces inside are only insignificant when a VERBOSE/comment/freespace mode is on.

It is safer to remove those spaces, and also add the end of line anchor (`$`):

```
^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])‌​[0-9]{11})$
```